# How can I get the Product Name in a Visual Studio post build event?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2015

I'm setting up a post build event to copy the DLL compiled by Visual Studio into my Unity project, but I can't get it to use the Product Name in the destination path. My command looks like this:

```
cd $(ProjectDir)
echo F|xcopy /Y "bin\release\$(AssemblyName).dll" "..\..\..\Assets\Plugins\$(ProductName)\$(AssemblyName).dll"
```

But that puts the file straight in the Plugins directory.

I can use $(RootNamespace) for some projects, but that won't work if I want a space in the folder name.

I know I could just put the product name in manually for each project, but is there a way to get Visual Studio to do it automatically like with the assembly name?

Comment: Why that puts the file straight in the Plugins directory? What's $(ProductName) in your case? I cannot find a marco named "ProductName".

Comment: $(ProductName) is nothing in my case because it doesn't exist as a macro (that's the problem). The path becomes .....Plugins\\$(AssemblyName)..... and so the file goes into Plugins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## For C/C++ projects,

Use [the Property Manager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/669zx6zc.aspx) (in the menu bar: View/Other Windows/Property Manager) to manage your projects' properties.

You can define a custom marco like $(ProjectName) in a new property sheet. And share the property sheet among your projects. Then you can use the marco in the  post build event of every project.

## For C# projects,

Use [the Property Functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633440.aspx).

[In Visual Studio 2012 (C#) How to Create Custom Macros available in Post Build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13632282/in-visual-studio-2012-c-how-to-create-custom-macros-available-in-post-build)

[MSBuild: Permanently Change PropertyGroup Property of a Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6347989/msbuild-permanently-change-propertygroup-property-of-a-project)

By the way, you can [use the environment variables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171459.aspx) if it is good for you.

Comment: The Property Manager is blank and says "No Visual C++ project is loaded". I'm using C# btw.

Comment: That stuff looks like it could probably do what I want so I'll mark your answer as correct, but I won't be using it since it would take far longer to figure out how to get what I need than just putting in the path I want for each project manually.